# I don't understand how to configure my security.yml file for the index page

Tags: symfony, firewall, fosuserbundle

I developed my symfony2 website with the required authentification (with FOSUserBundle).
Now I have decided to add 2 more exceptions for the anonymous visitors: The index page ("/") and the contact form ("/contact").

When I modify my security.yml, these get broken:

- In my twig contact form page, all of my "{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}" don't work anymore. It is really like I am not authentificated anymore.
- In my twig index page, I have the same problem, too.

Here is my security.yml.  I know that it can be trivial, but I don't find it in the doc where I can have more information on "keep me connected with authenticated session living" with the security.yml file. Everything I have tried doesn't work.

```
security:
    encoders:
        "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_AUTHOR:            ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:             [ROLE_USER, ROLE_AUTHOR]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:   ^/(login$|register|resetting)
            anonymous: true

        token:
            pattern:    ^/administration/create-user/confirmation-token/
            anonymous: true

        #this is where it fail....
        contact:
            pattern:    ^/contact$
            anonymous: true

        index:
            pattern:    ^/$
            anonymous: true


        # Main Firewall
        main:
            pattern: ^/+
            form_login:
                provider:    fos_userbundle
                remember_me: true
            remember_me:
                key:         %secret%
            anonymous:       false
            logout:          true
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        #- { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

you're doing it wrong :) You need to have only few firewalls. Not each firewall for each url.

do it in this way:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:        ^/
        switch_user:    true
        anonymous:      ~
        form_login:
            provider:   fos_userbundle
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:       /logout
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Next add another items into access_control.

Comment: Ok, I tried some stuffs, and everything was still broken.
I finally did that and it worked:
    contact:
        pattern:    ^/contact$
            form_login:
                provider:    fos_userbundle
                remember_me: true
            remember_me:
                key:         %secret%
            anonymous: true
            logout:          true

Comment: Dude you don't understand the symfony firewall. Check the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html
And the security.yml reference
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/security.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating different firewalls for contact and index, you have to add them to `access_control`, as they should be handled by the same firwall as the rest of your application (`main`), they only differ in that you want to modify which roles may access them:

```
main:
    pattern:        ^/
    ...
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/contact$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    #- { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

edit for clarification:
Specifying different firewalls like you did, puts those pages outside of your current security context and therefore the login from firewall main does not apply to these firewalls.

Comment: Ok sorry to bother you with that.
I tried many many possibilities. I still don't understand. Here is my security.yml: http://pastebin.com/rMwHemwg
And I get the error:
"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.") in ::layout.html.twig at line 33." Which is only because I have "{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}" in my template I guess.
It doesn't work only for the index page, and it works for the contact page.I become crazy